# Chrome Autofill wrong fields when saved password

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, autocomplete

I have 2 form in my website.
If I saved the email and password and other form have input password,
It will autofill email on last one input box (type=text)

I try to add autocomplete=off autocomplete=contact_no name=contact_no
but It doesn't work.

```
    <form>
      login form
      <br>
      <label> email<input type="text" /> </label>
      <label> password <input type="password"/> </label>

      <button type="submit"> submit</button>
    </form>

    <form>
      member update form
      <br>
      <label> readonly email <input type="text"readonly value="abc@google.com"/> </label>
      <label> contact_no <input type="text" name="contact_no" autocomplete="off"/> </label>
      <label> password <input type="password" name="password"/> </label>
      <button type="submit"> submit</button>
    </form>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/apple_W/pen/ZNoXLg)

https://upload.cc/i1/2019/05/26/jbBSxa.gif

https://upload.cc/i1/2019/05/26/lQmksB.png

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete

> In most modern browsers, setting autocomplete to "off" will not prevent a password manager >from asking the user if they would like to save username and password information, or from >automatically filling in those values in a site's login form.

To help chrome understand the form input better, you can try using autocomplete="tel" instead for the contact no